# Решение задачи "Время прибытия''

Tags: python, python-3.x

решал задачу с сайта acmp.ru

вот ссылка на саму задачу: https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=331

Мое решение не проходит 11 тест. Не могу понять, где именно ошибка, вроде на всех данных, которые я проверял всё работает корректно.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!
Вроде всё проверил, но так и не проходит тест

**Условие:**

Задано время отправления поезда и время в пути до конечной станции. Требуется написать программу, которая найдет время прибытия этого поезда (возможно, в другие сутки).

**Входные данные**

Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит две строки. В первой строке задано время отправления, а во второй строке – время в пути. Время отправления задается в формате «HH:MM», где HH время в часах, которое принимает значение от 00 до 23, ММ – время в минутах, которое принимает значение от 00 до 59. Время в пути задается двумя неотрицательными целыми числами – количество часов и количество минут. Числа разделяются одним пробелом. Количество часов не превышает 120, минут – 59.

**Выходные данные**

Выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT должен содержать одну строку – время прибытия поезда на конечную станцию. Формат вывода этого времени совпадает с форматом ввода времени отправления.

**Примеры:**

**тест №1**

INPUT.TXT

```
00:00
10 10
```

OUTPUT.TXT

```
10:10
```

**тест №2**

INPUT.TXT

```
01:02
4 6
```

OUTPUT.TXT

```
05:08
```

**тест №3**

INPUT.TXT

```
11:00
22 0
```

OUTPUT.TXT

```
09:00
```

Вот само решение(т.к код не самый читаемый добавил комментарии):

```
        
inp = open('222.txt','r')
out = open ('11.txt','w')
a = inp.read().split()# прочитал файл
#получаю  время отправления : часы и минуты
t = a[0]
h = int(t[:2])
m = int(t[3:])
# рассмотриваю отдельно случай ,когда время отправления равняется 00:00
if h == 0 and m == 0:
    # перевожу в минуты  время в пути 
    c =int(a[1]) * 60 + int(a[2])
    # рассматриваю случай с переход через сутки 
    if c >= 1440:
        q = abs(1440 - c)
        while q > 1440:
            q = abs(1440 - q)
        # получаю часы и минуты     
        hours = q // 60
        minutes = q % 60
        #записываю ответ 
        ans_hours = str(hours)
        ans_minutes = str(minutes)
        if len(ans_hours) == 1:
            ans_hours = '0' + ans_hours
        if len(ans_minutes) == 1:
            ans_minutes = '0' + ans_minutes
        out.write(ans_hours + ':' + ans_minutes)
    # рассматриваю случай ,когда перехода через сутки нету 
    else:
        # получаю часы и минуты 
        hours = c // 60
        minutes = c % 60
        # записываю ответ 
        ans_hours = str(hours)
        ans_minutes = str(minutes)
        if len(ans_hours) == 1:
            ans_hours = '0' + ans_hours
        if len(ans_minutes) == 1:
            ans_minutes = '0' + ans_minutes
        out.write(ans_hours + ':' + ans_minutes)
# рассматриваю общий случай
else:
    # перевожу в минуты  время в пути и время отправления 
    m_b = h*60 + m
    c = m_b+int(a[1])*60+int(a[2])
    # рассматриваю случай с переход через сутки 
    if c >=1440:
        q = abs(1440 - c)
        while q > 1440:
            q = abs(1440 - q)
        # получаю часы и минуты
        hours = q //60
        minutes = q %60
        # записываю ответ
        ans_hours = str(hours)
        ans_minutes = str(minutes)
        if len(ans_hours)==1:
            ans_hours = '0'+ans_hours
        if len(ans_minutes) == 1:
            ans_minutes = '0' + ans_minutes
        out.write(ans_hours+':'+ans_minutes)
    # рассматриваю случай с переход через сутки 
    else:
        # получаю часы и минуты
        hours = c // 60
        minutes = c % 60
        # записываю ответ
        ans_hours = str(hours)
        ans_minutes = str(minutes)
        if len(ans_hours) == 1:
            ans_hours = '0' + ans_hours
        if len(ans_minutes) == 1:
            ans_minutes = '0' + ans_minutes
        out.write(ans_hours + ':' + ans_minutes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Вариант №1

**1.**
Решение можно упростить, осознав, что количество часов большее чем 24, на ответ не влияет. Прибытие поезда через 36 часов, означает прибытие через 1 сутки и 12 часов. Время прибытия от количества суток не меняется и будет одинаковым хоть через 1 сутки, хоть через 3-е суток.

**Пример:**

Поезд отправился в `10:10`, был в пути 56 часов 35 минут.

56 часов 35 минут это `48 часов (2-е суток) + 8 часов 35 минут`. Сутки нам не нужно учитывать, поэтому их можно отбросить.

Таким образом, время прибытия будет `10:10 + 8 часов 35 минут = 18:45`.

**2.**
Можно все вычисления производить в минутах, чтобы не отслеживать, когда в результате сложения минут, появляется дополнительный час.

**Пример:**

`10:10 + 5:55` можно представить как `610 минут + 295 минут = 905 минут`. Потом перевести минуты обратно в формат `часы:минуты`: `905 минут = 15:05`

**Решение**

```
departure_hours, departure_minutes = map(int, input().split(':'))
duration_hours, duration_minutes = map(int, input().split())

# Переводим значения времени в минуты.
departure_time_in_minutes = departure_hours * 60 + departure_minutes
duration_time_in_minutes = duration_hours * 60 + duration_minutes 

# Вычисляем время прибытия в минутах.
arrival_time_in_minutes = departure_time_in_minutes + duration_time_in_minutes

### Переводим время в минутах обратно в формат "часы:минуты":

# Часы узнаём, разделив время в минутах на 60.
# Количество часов кратное 24 можно отбросить с помощью "% 24".
arrival_hours = (arrival_time_in_minutes // 60) % 24

# Количество минут это то, что осталось от деления на 60
arrival_minutes =  arrival_time_in_minutes % 60

print(f"{arrival_hours:02d}:{arrival_minutes:02d}")
```

---

#### Вариант №2

Можно обойтись и без перевода в минуты, в данном случае в этом нет необходимости. Тогда решение получается проще. Однако приём с переводом временных значений к одному знаменателю, будь то минуты или секунды, является типичным для задач подобного рода, поэтому оставлю его как **Вариант №1**.

```
departure_hours, departure_minutes = map(int, input().split(':'))
duration_hours, duration_minutes = map(int, input().split())

carry_hour, arrival_minutes = divmod((departure_minutes + duration_minutes), 60) 

arrival_hours = (departure_hours + duration_hours + carry_hour) % 24

print(f"{arrival_hours:02d}:{arrival_minutes:02d}")
```